# I installed 64 bit Ubuntu with wubi but I need to reinstall 32 bit version instead.

Tags: installation, 12.10, partitioning, wubi, 32-bit

I don't need to save data or anything but I'm aware that, because I used Wubi, it has partitioned the hard drive in ways that I don't understand and I don't think I can keep making more and more partitions.

The installation was the latest version (12.10).

I'm running an HP mini 210 with an atom processor and a relatively small HDD (215GB with 81GB free). I know that HP already partition the drives in these things in strange ways and also that the first Ubuntu installation did the same thing, so I'm running out of space.

Does anyone know the best way to do this, ie: reinstall a 32 bit version in the same partition that the 64 bit installation used?

I just wanted to make this puny little netbook run faster, but there's not much performance difference and I'm sure the 32 bit Ubuntu would help.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Wubi doesn't partition your drive. It creates a virtual partition (that is actually a file `\ubuntu\disks\root.disk`. You can't overinstall 32bit over a 64bit wubi. You'd need to uninstall and then install the 32bit again (use the `--32bit` command line option). Reinstalling will delete everything on the Wubi install. I doubt that the 32bit will run any faster though.

Answer (score 3):

This was answered in a comment:

> Wubi doesn't partition your drive. It creates a virtual partition
>   (that is actually a file `\ubuntu\disks\root.disk`. You can't
>   overinstall 32bit over a 64bit wubi. You'd need to uninstall and then
>   install the 32bit again (use the `--32bit` command line option).
>   Reinstalling will delete everything on the Wubi install. I doubt that
>   the 32bit will run any faster though.

– [bcbc](https://askubuntu.com/users/14916/bcbc) [Nov 18 '12 at 19:50](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218819/i-installed-64-bit-ubuntu-with-wubi-but-i-need-to-reinstall-32-bit-version-inste#comment270601_218819)